# View in empty template

Tags: iphone, view

I need to create my own view with controller on empty template without help of Interface Builder. What i need to write in AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode -> New project -> Select Window Based Template. Then Remove MainWindow.xib from resources, from info.plist remove this key "Main Nib file base name".In your main.m file 
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); // 4th parameter is name of your AppDelegate. In your AppDelegate.h remove property/synthesize for your IBOutlet UIWindow as you are not using IB at all..

```
// In your AppDelegate.m    
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

            // In your AppDelegate.h AnotherViewController* mainViewController;
            mainViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
            [[mainViewController view] setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
            [window addSubView:[mainViewController view]];
    }

// In your AnotherViewController implement 
- (void)loadView
{
  // Lets say you have a UITableView
  UITableView* tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
  [self setView:tableView];
}
```

Comment: Whats not working. I have updated my code. AnotherViewController* mainViewController declare as iVar. and showed you how loadView method of that viewController